# Problem with move_uploaded_file(); ($_POST)

Tags: php, file, post

```
if(isset($_POST['Descrizione']) && isset($_POST['ID']) && isset($_POST['File'])) {
    $info = pathinfo($_POST['File'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($info == "gif") {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['File']['name'], "/ms-swf/c_images/album1584");
    }
}
```

I would like to move a file uploaded with $_POST method. How can I do that? If I can. And if not, how can I fix that to make it working? Thank you

Comment: Turn on error_reporting you need `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

Comment: `$_POST['File']` is not the same as `$_FILES['File']`

Answer (score 0):

The `move_uploaded_file` function requires using the `tmp_name` of the file that has been uploaded.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['File']['tmp_name'], "/ms-swf/c_images/album1584");
```

Comment: That is still not moving the file.

Comment: OK can you do  `var_dump($_FILES); var_dump($_POST);` and edit your question with results. If `move_uploaded_file`  fails it will return `false`, but also raise a warning if it cannot write to the destination.

Comment: Could you explain me more clearly?

Comment: Your question says that the file isn't being moved. We need to find out WHY it isn't being moved. It could be that `move_uploaded_file` is never called because the `if` statement does not evaluate as true.